# My rewrite rule is not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to make a rewrite rule for a page, but it does not work.
I do have mod_rewrite for apache enabled

This is my .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^gameofthrones/(full|house|characters)\.(all|Stark|Lannister)\.(html|xml|json)$ index.php?output=$3&house=$2&info=$1
</IfModule>
```

But when I enter this url:
localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/index.php?output=html&house=all&info=full

It stays that way, but it should be something like:
localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/gameofthrones/full/all/html

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Comment: Could be a few things: A) You're set up so that it is you go to "localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/gameofthrones/full/all/html" then the site acts as if you went to "localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/index.php?output=html&house=all&info=full"

Comment: B) You're in a local machine, is mod_rewrite working?

Comment: What do you mean with A? And how can I see if mod_rewrite is really working?

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the concept of URL rewriting.

Let's say I rewrite `/hello` to `index.php?get=hello`. This means that `index.php?get=hello` will still work, but if I write `/hello`, it will, under the hood, map that to `index.php?get=hello`.

So while the user's address bar reads `/hello`, he's actually viewing `index.php?get=hello`.

That does not cancel `index.php?get=hello`, that doesn't mean that if anyone accesses the page through that URL it will redirect the user to `/hello`.

Comment: @DijkeMark: It does work. If you access `localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/gameofthrones/full/all/html` do you not see the intended webpage?

Comment: @Truth actually he is seperating the parameters with dots not slashes.

Comment: @Truth No, I get an error. 404 Not Found

The requested URL /school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/gameofthrones/full/all/html was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Add another rule which actually redirects your non rewritten URLs to the rewritten form:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/index\.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^output=([^&]*)&house=([^&]*)&info=([^&]*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gameofthrones/%3.%2.%1? [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule gameofthrones/(full|house|characters)\.(all|Stark|Lannister)\.(html|xml|json)$ index.php?output=$3&house=$2&info=$1 [PT,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then call: `localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/index.php?output=html&house=all&info=full` which should redirect you to: `localhost/school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/gameofthrones/full.all.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be a directory problem:

- where is the ***.htaccess*** file located in the directory tree?
- where is the ***index.php*** located file?

If the ***index.php*** file is located in the same directory (I assume the same ./school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/) you have simply to add:

```
RewriteBase /school/str-webservices/eindopdracht/

after RewriteEngine On
```

I'm sorry if I don't understand the problem.

Bye.

Comment: Thx Thiem for the formatting (i'm writing using iPhone from the Ischia SeeSide)